# MySQL trigger if new value is not equal to varchar

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert, string

StackExchange, I'm trying to create a trigger in MySQL (before insert) that gives an error if the new value of "sifra" is not S, P, K, A or Z, but it I'm getting an error even if the said criteria is met.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE sifra VARCHAR(1);
SET sifra = NEW.sifra;
IF (sifra <> 'S' OR sifra <> 'P' OR sifra <> 'K' OR sifra <> 'A' OR sifra <> 'Z' ) THEN
    set msg = "Sifra mora biti S, P, K, A ili Z.";
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
END IF;
END
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you get an error. If for example `sifra` is `S` then the `sifra <> 'P'` will cause the error to appear. Change the `OR` into `AND`.

Comment: Perhaps simpler:  `sifra NOT IN ('S', 'P', ...)`